# Single-stat percentage change from initial value in graphite/grafana?

Tags: graphite, grafana

Is there a way to simply show the change of a value over the selected time period? All I'm interested in is the offset of the last value compared to the initial one. The values can vary above and below these over the time period, it's not really relevant (and would be exceptions in my case).

For an initial value of 100 and an final value of 105, I'd expect a single stat box displaying 5%.

I have the feeling I'm missing something obvious obvious, but can't find a method to display this deceptively simple task.

**Edit:**

I'm trying to create a scripted Grafana dashboard that will automatically populate disk consumption growth for all our various volumes. The data is already in Graphite, but for purposes of capacity management and finance planning (which projects/departments gets billed) it would be helpful for managers to have a simple and coarse overview of which volumes grow outside expected parameters.

The idea was to create a list of single-stat values with color coding that could easily be scrolled through to find abnormalities. Disk usage would obviously never be negative, but volatility in usage between the start and end of the time period would be lost in this view. That's not a big concern for us as this is all shared storage and such usage is expected to a certain degree.

The perfect solution would be to have the calculations change dynamically based on the selected time period.

I'm thinking that this is not really possible (at least not easily) to do with just Graphite and Grafana and have started looking for alternative methods. We might have to implement a different reporting system for this purpose.

**Edit 2**

I've tried implementing the suggested solution from Leonid, and it works after a fashion. The calculations seems somewhat off from what I expected though.

My test dashboard looks like follows:

[image: Storage Growth over 30 days]

If I were to calculate the change manually, I'd end up with roughly 24% change between the start (7,23) and end (8.96) value. Graphite calculates this to 19%. It's probably a reason for the discrepancy, probably something to do with it being a time-series and not discreet values?

As a sidenote: The example is only 30 days, even though the most interesting number would be a year. We don't have quite a year of data in Graphite yet and having a 30 day view is also interesting. It seems I have to implement several dashboards with static times.

Comment: What are the growth expected parameters?

Comment: We define "organic growth" as below 15% over a year. The cost for handling that would come out of the operations budget. What usually breaks that is active projects, which are funded differently and if they exceed that growth they are expected to cover that cost.

Comment: Query from my answer calculate exactly what you need. Just replace `'1m'` with `'1y'` (one year) in `timeShift` and `my_metric` with your disk usage metric.

Comment: I'll do another test with your suggestion when I'm back to work tomorrow. I did try something very similar and got a calculation out of it, but the result didn't match up with my manual control calculation. Thanks though, will update after I've testet this.

Comment: Please make sure your query result reduced to single value by `current` function. Check YourPanel->Edit->Options->BigValue->Value. It must be set to `current`, default is average.

Comment: You know, that's exactly it. I had already figured out that the displayed value was the average value by setting up the same query in a line graph and displaying the legend as a table max/min/average/current. From that, I could see what I wanted was the current value, although I had missed that setting until now. Thank you, you cracked it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You certainly can do that for some fixed period. For example following query take absolute difference betweent current metric value and value that metric has one minute ago (i.e. initial value) and then calculate it's percentage of inital value.

```
asPercent(absolute(diffSeries(my_metric, timeShift(my_metric, '1m'))), timeShift(my_metric, '1m'))
```

I believe you can't do that for time period selected in Grafana picker.

But is that really what you need? It's seems strange because as you said value can change in both directions. Maybe [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) would be more suitable for you? It's available in Graphite as [`stdev` function](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.stdev).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have been attempting something similar to this, but still not quite what I want. I realize this is not a typical request and I should probably have been more specific in my original question. I'll update that to explain what I'm trying to do here.